How to connect multiple lambda function to a unified api in Golang
I created a Golang hotel reservation application which uses GraphQL and dynamodb. I have a reservation module which has the CRUD functions. All the functions have their own APIs. like create has createReservation API, delete has deleteReservation API, and so on. I want to make a single API called Reservations as the unified API and it should direct to these functions. How to implement this?
I tried to connect the main.go file to multiple APIs. Like depending on the field it would direct to multiple handlers, but it's not working.
